# How do you use multiple css classes in HAML?

Tags: css, haml

If I am chaining multiple css classes where the HTML would come out looking like:

```
<a class="btn primary large">
```

How would I do this in HAML?  These guesses didn't work:

```
.btn-primary-large
."btn-primary-large"
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use dots instead of dashes:

```
.btn.primary.large
```

Answer (score 12):

Question didn't specifically ask for a Haml+Ruby solution, but here is one for those who are interested. It uses a literal array.

```
%a{ class: %w[btn primary large] }
```